# Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'challenge_player' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

Me and my friend are trying to make a minigame kind of discord bot. I am trying to make a challenge command that takes the id of the user-specified and asks whether they want to accept or not.

```
#imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#DISCORD PART#
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.command()
async def challenge(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Please specify a member!")
    elif member.bot:
        await ctx.send("Bot detected!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"**{member.mention} please respond with -accept to accept the challenge!**")
        challenge_player_mention = member.mention
        challenge_player = member.id

@client.command()
async def accept(ctx):
  if ctx.message.author.id == challenge_player:
    await ctx.send(f"{challenge_player_mention} has accepted!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("No one has challenged you!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
  
  await client.process_commands(message)

client.run("token")
```

Everything is working fine except for the accept command.

Here is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
  ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:/Users/impec/Downloads/bots/epic gamer bot/epic_gamer.py", line 30, in accept
  if ctx.message.author.id == challenge_player:
NameError: name 'challenge_player' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'challenge_player' is not defined
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`challenge_player` is defined locally, in the `challenge` function so you can access it from the `accept` function.
You need to declare `challenge_player` outside of your function and add `global challenge_player` inside your functions, same thing with `challenge_player_mention`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

challenge_player, challenge_player_mention = "", ""

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.command()
async def challenge(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    global challenge_player, challenge_player_mention
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Please specify a member!")
    elif member.bot:
        await ctx.send("Bot detected!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"**{member.mention} please respond with -accept to accept the challenge!**")
        challenge_player_mention = member.mention
        challenge_player = member.id

@client.command()
async def accept(ctx):
  global challenge_player, challenge_player_mention
  if ctx.message.author.id == challenge_player:
    await ctx.send(f"{challenge_player_mention} has accepted!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("No one has challenged you!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
  
  await client.process_commands(message)

client.run("token")
```

**PS:** Don't share your bot token on internet! Anyone could access your bot with it and do whatever they want with it. You should generate another one and use it.